# Issue on Revolution slider wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider

I am creating a slider like using revolution slider

[image]

I tried to add text under these images

1) Select `text html` from layer

but it's always-on the background image. I want Text under image? How can I do that?
Similarly, I have set `maximum visible item 7` from carousal settings and `space -250`, but now only 3 items visible

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom css class for test and add z indexes for text to take it on the image